# Fitting model using ets() where trend is not multiplicative

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using `ets()` model to fit the exponential models. I want to fit model where trend in not multiplicative. That is :

`fit<-ets(x_ts,model="ZAZ")`

If I use the above code, it will fit only model where trend is additive.But I want that model should also consider "ZNZ" (Simple Exponential Model). Is there a way to do it that is allowing all models accept where trend is multiplicative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you could do the following

```
fit1 <- ets(x_ts, model="ZNZ")
fit2 <- ets(x_ts, model="ZAZ")
fit <- if(fit1$aicc < fit2$aicc) fit1 else fit2
```